# Determine if $x=0$ is a point of relative extremum for $f(x)= \sin(x) + \frac{x^3}{6}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Determine if $x=0$ is a point of relative extremum for $f(x)= \sin(x)
> + \frac{x^3}{6}$

[I am trying to use this test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test)

Here,

$f(x)= \sin(x)
+ \frac{x^3}{6}$

$f'(x)=\cos(x) + \frac{x^2}{2} \Rightarrow f'(0)=1 \neq 0$

So I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: The first derivative is non-zero and therefore it is not a maximum.

Comment: "So I am unable to proceed further." I wouldn't worry too much, since you're already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test you're referring to is useful if the derivatives of the first (few) orders are zero, but:

> $f'(x)=\cos(x) + \frac{x^2}{2} \Rightarrow f'(0)=1 \color{blue}{\neq 0}$

So there is no extreme value and you don't need to proceed to the *higher order* derivative test.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first derivative is positive, the function increases at that point.

[image]